# Encode form input with base64 and send it via get method

Tags: php, base64

I have a form with one text field and a submit button. The form uses the get method to send input data. I want to decode the text field's user input to base64 and add it to the url instead of the plain text on submit button click.

For example: Instead of http://www.example.com/send.php?inputfield=hello_world I want to have the URL http://www.example.com/send.php?inputfield=[base64 encryption of "hello_world"].

Is there a pure php solution to do so? I know, it is implementable by using Javascript, but I would like to do it completely in PHP.

Comment: As it appears in the comment to Emil Vikström's answer, you don't need encryption. There might be another solution to your problem, but what problem exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: You should replace 'Encrypt' by 'Encode' ... There isn't any cryptography here with b64.

Answer (score 4):

This is a client-side problem so no, you cannot do it in PHP because the data is sent before PHP even touches it.

Also, don't confuse base64 with encryption because it is not safe in any way at all. It's made for transmission of binaries over text-based protocols, not for safety.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I know, base64 is not safe and easily to decrypt, but I just need to aggregate long texts with some special chars into a shorter shape with common letters.

Comment: @nullpointr You don't encrypt/decypt base64, you simply encode/decode it. There is nothing cryptographic about it.